# calling boost::asio::tcp::socket methods after async_read handler returned an error in server

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp

For log output i am calling `tcp::socket::remote_endpoint()` from a shared_ptr `Session` object when the `Session` is created and when it is destroyed. If an `async_read` is called and the client has sent a FIN before the server sends a reply and then an RST packet after the server has sent the reply (`write` doesn't return any errors), the `async_read` function returns error code `system::54` (not_connected - with a message of "Connection reset by peer") and then when i call the remote_endpoint method again (in the `Session` object destructor) it throws a exception:

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >: remote_endpoint: Invalid argument`

Does the `async_read` error invalidate the socket or is there another cause of this? I can't see anything in the boost::asio 1.59.0 docs.

I should probably add that this socket is the socket underlying a `boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket&>`

An example of the above occurs in this code:

```
void read() {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_read(ssl_stream_, boost::asio::buffer(buffer_),
    [this, self](const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t) {
        if (!ec) {
            processBuffer();
        } else {
            /* system:54 error occurs see here */
            std::cout << "read ec: " << ec << " " << ec.message() << std::endl;

            /* This will throw an exception (Invalid argument) */
            auto endpoint = socket_.remote_endpoint();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is the SSCCE? It looks like the socket got closed. Or Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Added example in edit

Comment: Is `boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket&>` correct? I think I've only ever seen `boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket>` before

Comment: Yes, i use both `tcp::socket` and `boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket&>` members in the `Session` class for easy access to the socket underneath the stream e.g. calling `tcp::socket::remote_endpoint`

Comment: I specifically meant the `&` in there.

Answer (score 2):

Is `boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket&>` correct? I think I've only ever seen `boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket>` before

Also

> I should probably add that this socket is the socket underlying a boost::asio::ssl::stream

You should be `async_read`-ing from the stream (after handshake). If the stream is in an SSL session, reading/writing from it directly will cause the SSL session to fail, and it might be closed down.

Comment: The ssl::stream uses a reference to a socket and the `Session` object owns the socket. No `async_read`s or `async_write`s are done directly to the socket, it's only used for getting the remote and previously the `native_handle` for debug purposes but not anymore. I think the RST which causes `ec` to be set to system:54 is the reason the `remote_endpoint` call is failing, SSL or not but i can't find documentation for it anywhere...

Comment: Just trying to find where i read about using `boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket&>`...

Comment: "In some use cases the underlying stream object will need to have a longer lifetime than the SSL stream, in which case the template parameter should be a reference to the stream type" http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/ssl.html

Comment: Cool. I didn't know that. Explains that it compiles :)

Comment: Yeah, if the socket got shutdown/closed, you cannot get the remote_endpoint anymore. I've noticed that a lot of times. No documentation about it

Comment: Do you know if the error causes the socket to be closed before the handler is invoked?

Comment: Yes.This is what I said. At the very least it makes the socket become invalid for calling `remote_endpoint`

Comment: Could you point me to some documentation of the socket close BEFORE the handler invocation?

Comment: @alexyoung I said that too.

Comment: @sehe I have gone through your example you gave. But there are errors in the code of  https request you sent and the code is on Coliru